# How to delete string in html tag? javascript jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to delete string in my website.My div html content is:

```
<br><b >1.jpg(10.36k)</b> <span class="delimg" id="cancelbtn">cancel</span><br><b >123.jpg(10.36k)</b> <span class="delimg" id="cancelbtn">cancel</span><br><b >test.jpg(83.19k)</b> <span class="delimg" id="cancelbtn">cancel</span>
```

I want to delete row which include 123.jpg.The rest code is:

```
<br><b >1.jpg(10.36k)</b> <span class="delimg" id="cancelbtn">cancel</span><br><b >test.jpg(83.19k)</b> <span class="delimg" id="cancelbtn">cancel</span>
```

In my website, before delete:

```
 1.jpg(10.36k)  cancel
 123.jpg(10.36k)  cancel
 test.jpg(83.19k)  cancel
```

After delete, my website will appear:

```
 1.jpg(10.36k)  cancel
 test.jpg(83.19k)  cancel
```

I suppose replace(new RegExp(filename,"g"),"")) would be OK.But i hava no idea about the filename string.Who can help me ?

Comment: You should not  have multiple element of the same id.
Also, you should be using an unordered list instead of breaks.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be:

```
$('b:contains(123.jpg)')
.prev('br')
.nextUntil('br')
.andSelf()
.remove();
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('b:contains(123.jpg)')
    .prev('br')
    .nextUntil('br')
    .andSelf()
    .remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><b >1.jpg(10.36k)</b> <span class="delimg" id="cancelbtn1">cancel</span>
<br><b >123.jpg(10.36k)</b> <span class="delimg" id="cancelbtn2">cancel</span>
<br><b >test.jpg(83.19k)</b> <span class="delimg" id="cancelbtn3">cancel</span>
```